# How to save 5 rows from mysqlidatabase and save them in array for later use?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I want to get 5 different rows by selecting them from my database using `mysqli_*` and save them in a variable by array. After saving, use the array variables in the page.

It should look like this:

```
// Create connection
$db_connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_servername, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$db_connection) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT url, title, summary, upload_date, id FROM video ORDER BY upload_date LIMIT 5"; 

$images= array();
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))){
  array_push($images, $row);
}

echo $images[0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[1][0];
echo"<br/>";
```

I want these data saved as an array, because I want to use it later in the same page for carousel.

I am using `mysqli_*` to connect to my database.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't that work? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an explanation of the problem.

Comment: i tried $images= array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    array_push($images, $row);
}

Comment: Please put that in the question, not the comments -- it's part of what you're asking, after all.

Comment: i edited it right now

Comment: Which API are you using to connect with? mysql_ - mysqli_ - PDO?

Comment: mysqli API i'm using

Comment: You're not connecting to your DB using `$result = mysqli_query($query)` will fail because it's missing the connection parameter. I.e.: `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query)` - Add `or die(mysqli_error($db_connection))` to `mysqli_query()` to debug.

Comment: it connects to database, just now i had edited the connection code... i just skipped that part where it connects to database.

Comment: Do this => `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);` - Again, you're NOT connecting. If that works, let me know.

Comment: yes. you are right. it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag and for example: 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code and see if it yields anything. Also do `$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));`

Comment: Also, your brace `}` is in the wrong spot. Do `while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) { array_push($images, $row);  
echo $images[0][0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[1][0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[3][0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[4][0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[5][0]; }`

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/u568469948/public_html/lol/page_layout/snippets/carousel.php on line 17
in that line is: echo $images[0][0];

Comment: Put it back where it was then and use the same thing I told you in regards to errors.

Comment: Also try and remove the second set of arrays. I.e. `echo $images[0];
echo"<br/>";
echo $images[1];`

Comment: after using what you said it throws:Array

Answer (score 1):

"from mysqli database"

Did you mean MySQL ? :)

Use PDO.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And save all 5 rows to an array with fetchAll() method - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: yes, MySQL. thank you for question, but how it should look like in PHP code? :)

Comment: `try {  
    $dbh = new PDO(  
        'mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME . ';host=' . DATABASE_HOST,
        DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS,  
        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)  
    );  
      
    $sql = 'your query';  
      
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
    $sth->execute();  
  
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
      
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
    // handle exception  
}`  
   
$result will store all rows as associative array.

Comment: and then how to get data from array?

Comment: use `print_r($result);` and guess how to do it with `foreach`  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Copied from W3school

Example (MySQLi Procedural)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Something like this?

```
$images= array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    array_push($images, $row);
}
```